# WCF Service and ajax call in same project

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, c#-4.0, web-applications

I hav a C# web application. In that I have added a WCF Service file (.svc) by Right Click project Add New Item >> WCF Service (wcfService.svc). ( Now I have IwcfService.cs and wcfService.cs in my App_Code folder) And also added a function `WCFXmlData(string id)` inside that.

I am trying to access the function inside wcf service file from an ajax call in my application (in an aspx file).
But I am not able to do that.

Also I tried to browse this .svc file directly. There I got a message like `Metadata publishing` for this service is currently disabled.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on your binding, if you use the [`WebHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412176.aspx) you can simple access the data via a browser. In best case you should modify your contract in such a way that it returns JSON, this is less overhead than XML or even SOAP (which uses also XML).

It your webpage is also implemented in the webservice you have nothing special to care about, but if your service runs under another subdomain you need to implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) to manage cross domain calls.